# Static variable in C

Tags: c, static

I have this program that is a part of a server with tcp protocol, that gets a number from the client and uses it in another function.
Also I have a `static int` type variable that i want to count each time the server gets a message from a client, but each time it does not keep its value;
The variable is `counter`
Can you guys tell me why this is happening?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// used port 
#define PORT 1114

// error code 
extern int errno;

static int counter;

int main ()
{
  struct sockaddr_in server;  // structure used by server
  struct sockaddr_in from;  
  char message[100];         //message received from client
  int socketDescriptor;     //socket descriptor 


  //creating socket
  if ((socketDescriptor = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror ("[server]Error at socket\n");
    return errno;
  }

  //preparing data structures
  bzero (&server, sizeof (server));
  bzero (&from, sizeof (from));

  //filling structures
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;  

  server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

  server.sin_port = htons (PORT);

  //attach socket to descriptor
  if (bind (socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
    perror ("[server]Error at bind\n");
    return errno;
  }

  //server is listening
  if (listen (socketDescriptor, 2) == -1)
  {
    perror ("[server]Error at listen\n");
    return errno;
  }

  /serving concurrent the clients

  while (1)
  {
    int client;
    int length = sizeof (from);

    printf ("[server]Waiting at port %d...\n",PORT);
    fflush (stdout);

    //accepting client

    client = accept (socketDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length);
    counter ++;
    switch(fork())
    {
      case -1: 
        perror("fork err\n");
        exit(2);
    case 0:
      //error if failed connection
      if (client < 0)
      {
        perror ("[server]Error at accept\n");
        continue;
      }
      //conenction established
      bzero (message, 100);
      printf ("[server]Waiting for message...\n");
      fflush (stdout);

      //reading message
      if (read (client, message, 100) <= 0)
      {
        perror ("[server]Error at read\n");
        close (client); //closing connection
        continue;   //keep listening
      }

      printf ("[server]Message was received%s\n", message);
      //this is where I want to increment counter, when I want to  verify     message

      int number;
      number = atoi(message);//convert char to int

      printf("The number is: %d\n", number);//print number

      printf("The counter is : %d\n", counter);

      fflush(stdout);

  exit(2);
    }
  close (client);
  }      /* while */
}       /* main */
```

Comment: You didn't post the declaration of `counter`!

Comment: Done, forgot about it, it was outside main. Now it's inside, towards the end of the program.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this code. You call `fork()` inside a loop. Then your child process starts executing, and then it goes back to the beginning of the loop so your child process then itself calls fork() and creates another child process. How many child/grandchild/great-grandchild processes are you intending to create?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou good observation, a missing `_exit(0)` perhaps.

Comment: You guys are right. Didn't notice that. I must re-eval my code.

Comment: To insure code fails to read a _string_: `if (read (connfd, message, 100) <= 0) ... message[99] = 0;`  Add this last bit or make `message` 1 bigger than used by `read()` with a zero-ed last element.

Comment: @chux, you mean `ssize_t length; if ((length = read(connfd, message, 99) <= 0) ... else message[length] = '\0';` right?

Comment: @iharob Something like that.  OP has not posted `MAXLINE` as used in `char message[MAXLINE]`.  Your suggestion would work is `MAXLINE >= 100`.

Comment: What is `MAXLINE`? Why 100 in `read (connfd, message, 100)`?

Comment: I've updated the code to be more readable, and the `counter` works, but it still increments even though the message is empty. I want it to increment after, let's say, I'd verify that the `message` is a string representing a number and/ or is not empty, which occurs in the child process

Comment: What you could do is have the child process return 1 for error and 0 for success. Note the statement in your code `continue;   //keep listening` is wrong as this statement is actually in the child process. It should be replaced by `exit(1);`. Then in the parent process, get the exit status of the child process and if its a success, increment the counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move `counter++` to the parent process. When the child process starts it gets a copy of `counter` and the one you modify does not affect it's copy (original actually) in the parent process. If you update it in the parent process you will achieve what you want.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int number;
    int listenfd, connfd, n;
    pid_t childpid;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char message[MAXLINE], answer[MAXLINE];
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr, serveraddr;
    int counter;

    counter = 0;
    // create socket
    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR at creating socket\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    // preparation of socket address
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // bind the socket
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

    // listen to the socket
    listen(listenfd, LIMIT);

    printf("Server running, waiting for connections at port : %d\n", PORT);

    while (1)
    {
        clilen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        // accept a connection
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clilen);
        printf("Recieved guest\n");
        switch (fork())
        {
        case -1:
            perror("fork err\n");
            exit(2);
        case 0:
            /* eroare la acceptarea conexiunii de la un client */
            if (connfd < 0)
            {
                perror("[server]Eroare la accept().\n");
                continue;
            }

            /* s-a realizat conexiunea, se astepta mesajul */
            bzero(message, 100);
            printf("[server]Asteptam mesajul...\n");
            fflush(stdout);

            /* citirea mesajului */
            if (read(connfd, message, 100) <= 0)
            {
                perror("[server]Eroare la read() de la client.\n");
                close(connfd); /* inchidem conexiunea cu clientul */

                continue;   /* continuam sa ascultam */
            }
            printf ("[server]Message was received...%s\n", message);
            fflush(stdout);

            number = atoi(message);

            printf("The number is: %d\n", number);
            printf ("%d\n", counter + 1);
            _exit(0); // The child should not create further grand children
        default:
            counter++;
            break;
        }//switch
    }//for
    close(connfd);
}//main
```

Comment: But as a ` static `, shouldn't it be NOT affected, but keeps it's value in the entire program?

Comment: Yes, in the entire program. But once you `fork()` a copy of the memory space is created for the child, and then you cannot affect the parent anymore, unless you use shared memory but that is not necessary in this case.

Comment: so i moved the `counter` right above `switch(fork())`, i does increment, but not if the message is the same from the client.

Comment: And it seems it does not break the limit of 4.

Comment: @Justplayit94 There is a new edit after some one who commented on your question pointed out another mistake. Also, you MUST ensure that the `read()` reads the termination `nul` byte, other wise you can add it after `read()`.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be forking before setting the counter.  Since [forking duplicates the entire process](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), the copy of counter in each child process is different from the parent.

Sharing variables between applications in C can be tricky, but actually there's a pretty easy fix for your case and it will improve performance too.  If you look at your code, you're forking after the connect and then handling, in the child, the possibiliy that the `connfd < 0`.  If you handled that in the parent process, the counter could belong to the parent and could be incremented *before* the fork.

A few other notes here come to mind.  Remember, fork *duplicates* the parent process, so the children in your case are still within a `while(1)` loop.  When you `continue` you loop back to the next iteration of the `while(1)` loop, but this doesn't seem correct; you want the child process to *exit* when it's done handling the connection.   This also means as you accept connections, you fork but the fork never dies - I guess that's more a "process leak" than a memory leak, but will certainly eat up memory.  Finally, just to throw it out there, forking to handle each request is probably the slowest way to concurrently handle connections.  I've had great success with pthread in this case.  Since threads share a process space, the threads can even persist and handle many connections before dying ( put the connections on a queue and have the threads poll it, for example ) becasuse they can continue to share connections with their "parent" ( though it's really a sibling thread in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm trying actually to make a Connect 4 game between 2 players for a project at my college. And it's really bugging me out.

Comment: Maybe c is a prerequisite for this project, but if you're free to choose the implementation and delivery mechanism - HTML all the way on this one.  It would really help simplify the presentation, handle the network layer for you, and of ourse make your game playable for anyone with a browser without building a whole ton of client apps or distributing them.

Comment: I am being constrained to use C. It has to be only a console type of application.